# How to find eigenvalues of a Pauli matrix resolved direct product matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a $2 \times 2$ hermitian matrix one can resolve the matrix
in terms of Pauli matrices like this
\begin{align}
 H &= \begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
  b & -a
 \end{pmatrix} \\
 &= a \sigma_z + b \sigma_x  \\
\end{align}
Here, I've assumed $ a,b \in \mathbb{R} $, Using Pauli matrix identities one
can find the eigenvalues of $H$ are $\pm \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

I was thinking if this process can be generalized for higher dimensional matrices.
Lets say, we have a $(2n\times2n)$ matrix and this matrix can be written in terms of
Pauli matrices
\begin{align}
 H = \sigma_{x}\otimes \mathbf{A} + \sigma_{y}\otimes \mathbf{B}
\end{align}
For example we set $n=2$
\begin{align}
 \mathbf A = \begin{pmatrix}
  e_1 & 0 \\
  0 & e_2
 \end{pmatrix} \\
 \mathbf B = \begin{pmatrix}
  b_1 & b_2 \\
  b_2 & b_4
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Can I find the eigenvalues using Pauli matrix identities as the $2\times2$ matrix, here also?

In $2\times2$ matrix one would do
\begin{align}
 H^2 = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a^2+b^2 & 0 \\
 0 & a^2+b^2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
E^2 =\left(   
\begin{array}{cc}
 a^2+b^2 & 0 \\
 0 & a^2+b^2 \\
\end{array}
\right) 
\end{align}
Thus one obtains the eigenvalue of H as $E=\pm \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

When I'm doing the same thing here
\begin{align}
 H^2 &= (\sigma_{x}\otimes \mathbf{A} + \sigma_{y}\otimes \mathbf{B})^2  \\
 \implies E^2 \mathbb{I}_{2n} &= \sigma_x\sigma_x \otimes \mathbf{A}^2 + \sigma_y\sigma_y\otimes \mathbf{B}^2
 -\sigma_x\sigma_y \otimes \mathbf{A}\mathbf{B} - \sigma_y\sigma_x\otimes \mathbf{B}\mathbf{A} \\
 \implies E^2 \mathbb{I}_{2n}&=  \mathbb{I}_2 \otimes \mathbf{A}^2 + \mathbb{I}_2\otimes \mathbf{B}^2
 +i\sigma_z \otimes \mathbf{A}\mathbf{B} - i\sigma_z\otimes \mathbf{B}\mathbf{A} \\
 \implies E^2 \mathbb{I}_{2n}&=  \mathbb{I}_2 \otimes (\mathbf{A}^2 + \mathbf{B}^2) + i \sigma_z \otimes [\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}]
\end{align}
Here $[\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}] = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{B} - \mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}$.
Now, when I take trace of the last equation $(n =2)$
\begin{align}
4 E^2 = Tr \mathbf{A}^2 + Tr \mathbf{B}^2 
\end{align}
There should be no other terms as Pauli matrices are traceless,
so
\begin{align}
 E = \pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4 + b_1^2 + 2 b_2^2 + b_4^2 + e_1^2 + e_2^2}
\end{align}
Both of the solutions are 2 fold degenerate,
But the solutions are wrong, Mathematica gives some complicated and totally different output
\begin{align}
 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\lambda-\sqrt{\lambda^2-4 \delta}\right)} \\
 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\lambda-\sqrt{\lambda^2+4 \delta}\right)} \\
 - \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\lambda-\sqrt{\lambda^2-4 \delta}\right)} \\
 - \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\lambda-\sqrt{\lambda^2-4 \delta}\right)} \\
\end{align}

Here $\lambda =  Tr \mathbf{A}^2 + Tr \mathbf{B}^2$, and $\delta = \text{Det}\: H$.

What I'm doing wrong here and how to get the correct expressions?

Comment: You are using some strange notation. What is $H.H$? What is $E$ supposed to be?

Comment: Also, why does the term $\mathbf C$ disappear from your equations? Are you setting $\mathbf C = 0$?

Comment: H is a matrix. Fixed the typo of $H.H$., And $E$ is the eigenvalue of the corresponding $H$ matrix. Fixed the typos.

Comment: I suspect that you can generalize the $2 \times 2$ approach to $2^n \times 2^n$ matrices by writing $\mathbf{A,B}$ as sums of Pauli matrices.

Comment: Another typo: in your expansion of $H^2$, you switch from $\sigma_x$ to $\sigma_z$.

Comment: You might find it helpful to consider what the eigenvalues look like in the case that $b_2 = 0$ (so that $[A,B] = 0)$.  We should end up with eigenvalues
$$
\pm \sqrt{e_1^2 + b_1^2}, \quad \pm \sqrt{e_2^2 + b_4^2}.
$$
Since we are considering conformally partitioned block-diagonal matrices, this "nice" kind of result is perhaps to be expected.

Comment: Looking at the characteristic polynomial does give some insights. For a $2n \times 2n$ dimensional $H$, the coefficients of all odd orders in the polynomial goes to zero, so we expect that the solutions should be in the form $\{E_1,-E_1,E_2,-E_2\}$. This is due to the fact the eigen values of Pauli matrices are $\{1,-1\}$

Comment: @Galiliean Regarding your statment "for a $2n \times 2n$ dimensional $H$, the coefficients of all odd orders in the polynomial goes to zero": is this something that you have shown, or is this something that you have found "empirically" with Mathematica? Or, are you specifically referring to the $n=2$ case?

Comment: I just found it out. This has to be the case because a direct product with Pauli matrices will force the eigenvalues to have a $\pm$ structure. If this were not the case, $H$ would never resolve in terms of Pauli Matrices. @Omnomnomnom

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "a direct product with Pauli matrices will force the eigen values to have a $\pm $ structure". I can agree that $\sigma_x \otimes A$ and $\sigma_y \otimes B$ will each (separately) have eigenvalues in a $\pm$ structure. However, I don't see why this implies that their sum should have this same structure.

Comment: Note that **every** Hermitian $4 \times 4$ matrix can be written in the form
$$
\sum_{j,k=0}^4 a_{jk} \sigma_j \otimes \sigma_k,
$$ 
where $\sigma_0 = I, \sigma_1 = \sigma_x, \sigma_2 = \sigma_y, \sigma_3 = \sigma_z$, and the $a_{ij}$ are real numbers.

Comment: Your notation is a bit unclear. If you are trying to say that 
$$
\sigma_x \otimes A + \sigma_y \otimes B + \sigma_z \otimes C
$$
will generally have eigenvalues in $\pm$ pairs (for Hermitian $A,B,C$), then I suspect that this statement is false. It is true, however, that the eigenvalues necessarily come in $\pm$ pairs if $C = 0$ (or if any one of $A,B,C$ is zero).

Comment: Now, I got your point. This is absolutely correct. The $\pm$ pair form of eigenvalues is indeed not a general solution. But, in a very special case when $B^T = B$ and $C^T = C$, and $A^T=A$, i.e. all of these are symmetric matrices, then I think the $\pm$ pairs are the only possible solution. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's an interesting conjecture; I can't think of a way to prove that. If it holds for random choices of symmetric $A,B,C$, then I suspect that you're right.

Comment: Note that your conjecture is equivalent to showing that the matrices
$$
\pmatrix{C & A - iB\\ A + iB & -C}, \quad -\pmatrix{C & A - iB\\ A + iB & -C}
$$
are similar for any choice of symmetric and real $A,B,C$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $C$ (or any one of $A,B,C$) is diagonal.

Comment: Your conjecture is correct. It suffices to note that a matrix $M$ of your form is similar to
$$
([I_2 \otimes (\sigma_z \sigma_x)]M[I_2 \otimes (\sigma_z \sigma_x)]^{-1})^T = -M.
$$

Comment: Never mind, I was careless; the trick I used assumes that $B = 0$. In that case, it's actually easy to see that $(\sigma_y \otimes I)M(\sigma_y \otimes I)^{-1} = -M$.

Comment: Now that I check again, my proof was fine: the key is that $A - iB$ is equal to its own transpose (is complex-symmetric). Your conjecture is correct and proven after all; sorry for the back and forth there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your assumption that $H^2 = E^2 I_{2n}$.

In the $2 \times 2$ case, we use the equation $H^2 = E^2 I_2$ in order to exploit the fact that any trace-zero $2 \times 2$ matrix $H$ will be such that $H^2$ is a multiple of the identity.  However, this trick no longer works in the generalized setting since it is no longer true that a trace-zero Hermitian matrix $H$ is such that $H^2$ is a multiple of the identity.